# ElasticSearch percolate over a set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, elasticsearch, tire

From [tire gem's DSL example](https://github.com/karmi/tire/blob/master/examples/tire-dsl.rb#L832) the following code was given.

```
index = Tire.index('weather') do
  delete
  create

  # First, a query named _warning_,
  register_percolator_query('warning', :tags => ['warning']) { string 'warning OR severe OR extreme' }

  # a query named _tsunami_,
  register_percolator_query('tsunami', :tags => ['tsunami']) { string 'tsunami' }
end


matches = index.percolate(:message => '[Warning] Extreme flooding expected after tsunami wave.')
```

I was wondering how can we set the matching criteria to a set of terms instead of ORed string.

For instance `string 'warning weather OR severe weather OR extreme weather'` would match `warning` or `weather` and not both `warning weather` together.

Comment: Found your solution? Seen my answer? How did you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I am studying ElasticSearch because I will use it soon, but I did not use it yet so I can try and share my thin knowledge :)

Please check their doc http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/query-string-query/

And look at the `default_operator` setting, I guess you need to set it to `AND`